# How to find transient and asymptote dynamics in a numerical series in R

Tags: r, transient

The following is essential for me to move forward on in my research.

I am trying to find a way to compute for large data sets the duration of the transient and asymptote dynamics. Here is a short example of how my data looks like.

```
x <- c(6,3,8,9,4,3,2,9,8,6,7,1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1,1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1,1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1,1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1,1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1,1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1,1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1,1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1,1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1,1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1,1)
plot(x, type="l")
```

[image]

I had a look at the first and second derivative but did not work as I wanted.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The duration of the transient dynamics should be 17.  For the rest of the time series, the period remains constant.

Comment: Like this `plot(c(x[1:17], rep(mean(x[-(1:17)]), length(x[-(1:17)]))), type="l")`?

Comment: What do you mean by 17? Is it the point where the graph stabilizes?

Comment: @Onyambu Sorry for my late reply. I think the tipping point is 11 and not 17.

Comment: @LDT Did you not see my solution below? A change point analysis using default parameters picks up the changepoint at index 11. You could follow this up with a piecewise linear regression model to characterise what you call "transient" and "asymptotic" dynamics of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided I understood correctly, you could explore a [change point analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_detection).

There exists an R package called `changepoint` that implements various changepoint search methods, details can be found in [the original publication](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v058i03/v58i03.pdf).

Here is an example using your sample data.

```
library(changepoint);
ret <- cpt.mean(x, class = FALSE);
ret;
#cpt conf.value
#11.0000000  0.9406066
```

In the output, `cpt` is the most probable location of a changepoint. If you zoom into the plot, you can see that this seems sensible.

```
plot(x, type="l", xlim = c(0, 20));
abline(v = ret[1], col = "red")
```

[image]

Obviously you need to have a closer look at some of the "tuning" parameters. `?cpt.mean` and the paper will be a good starting point.

You could then classify events `x < cpt` as transient, and `x > cpt` as asymptotic; but that of course depends on the context/source of your data which I don't know.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I used the cpt.meanvar option and I could detect the exact point of the transient dynamics every time. Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: @LDT No worries, glad to help. If this answers your question, please consider closing the question by by setting the check mark next to the solution.